# Problem to deserialize JSON class Kotlin with Spring Boot JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm having a problem with a Rest API with Spring Boot JPA and Kotlin. An error is thrown every time I try to insert a new record using the POST endpoint.

The error log that appears:

JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.lp3bmobi.paintcar_workshop_api.model.VehicleType` (although at least one Creator exists): no int / Int-argument constructor / factory method to deserialize from Number value (3)

**VehicleType Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="vehicle_types")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener::class)
@JsonDeserialize
data class VehicleType (
        @NotBlank
        @Column(name = "type_name")
        var typeName: String ?= null
        //@JsonProperty("typeName") var typeName: String ?= null
) {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    var id: Long ?= null
    //@JsonProperty("id") var id: Long = 0

    constructor(id: Long, typeName: String?): this(typeName) {
        this.id = id
    }

   //    @JsonCreator constructor(id: Long, typeName: String?): this(typeName) {
   //        this.id = id
   //    }

}
```

**Vehicle Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="vehicles")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener::class)
data class Vehicle (
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        var id: Long ?= null,

        @NotBlank
        @Column(name = "model_name")
        var modelName: String ?= null,

        @NotBlank
        @Column(name = "year")
        var year: Int ?= null,

        @NotBlank
        @Column(name = "brand_id")
        var brand: Int ?= null,

        @NotBlank
        @Column(name = "description")
        var description: String ?= null,

        @NotBlank
        @Column(name = "approved")
        var approved: Boolean ?= null,

        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) //cascade = arrayOf(CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "vehicle_type_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
        var vehicleType: VehicleType,
        //@JsonProperty("vehicleType") var vehicleType: VehicleType ?= null,
)
```

**VehicleController**

```
@PostMapping("/vehicle/new")
fun createVehicle(@RequestBody vehicle: Vehicle): ResponseEntity<Vehicle?>? { //EntityModel<Vehicle>
        try {
          val _vehicle: Vehicle = vehicleRepository
                  //.save(Vehicle(vehicle.content))
                 //.save(Vehicle(0, vehicle.modelName, vehicle.year, vehicle.brand,
                //              vehicle.description, false, vehicle.vehicleType))
                .save(vehicle)
           return ResponseEntity<Vehicle?>(_vehicle, HttpStatus.CREATED)
       } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
           return ResponseEntity<Vehicle?>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    }
}
```

Comment: As a point of style, `String ?= null` etc. is confusing!  Kotlin has no `?=` operator.  Took me quite a few moments to work out that that's just `String? = null`, i.e. a parameter of type nullable String, which defaults to null.  Amazing how much difference spacing can make to humans, even if the compiler doesn't care…

Comment: Delete the constructor. It needs a zero arg constructor that it fills in using reflection to convert from json to an object. When you set a value to a default like you have by setting them to null you actually get n+1 constructors in koltin. If anything you might need to create a zero arg constructor. Also, as a side note it's a best practice (feel free to disagree) to create separate request or response classes that are not entities so you are explicitly deciding  which fields to take in/ sent out. Ex: by taking in an id and using JPAs save method it's easy to overwrite someone else's data

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems to be saying that Spring can't find a constructor for `VehicleType` taking a single Int argument, so the obvious thing is to give it one!

You could do that by adding another secondary constructor:

```
constructor(id: Int): this(null) {
    this.id = id.toLong()
}
```

(Disclaimer: I haven't tried it myself…  Please let us know if it works!)

If the existing secondary parameter took an Int instead of a Long, then another option would be to give a default value for its other parameter.  (In that case you'd also need to add a [`@JvmOverloads`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-overloads/) annotation, to ensure that it generates the additional constructor in the bytecode.)

I'm not sure why it's trying to use an Int when the property is defined as a Long; maybe it's to do with the `referencedColumnName = "id"` column?  In any case, Kotlin is a bit stricter than languages like Java or C about the difference between Longs and Ints (and other numeric types).

Comment: The same error continues even following your suggestion, adding the secondary constructor with the parameter int